# ASP.NET Profile not updating certiain values? Probably a code issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile

Alright, so I've been trying to make an ASP.NET website that uses **basic profiling features**, and so far I'm running into trouble with the code I have to display and edit profile information.

Basically, in the top part of my page, it shows your **"Screenname" and "Bio"** - both defined in the same way in the web.config (below). In my page, I have **two textboxes and a save button, IDed as AssignScreenname, AssignBio, and ChangeProfileSaveButton**. When the save button is clicked, **an if &  else if each run to check if either box is null or an empty string, and if one isn't that one's value is assigned to the profile**. Then, the code calls Profile.save() and redirects you back to the same page to insure a complete refresh of the entire page.

My problem is that **when you assign one value, the other value gets scratched out**. For example, assigning a Bio value means that any pre-existing Screenname value gets erased. I don't understand why it does this, because it should only be assigning the boxes to the profile is there is no text in them.

I also found it interesting that **removing Profile.Save() did nothing**, so maybe the problem has something to do with that?

Codes: 
The  element of my Web.Config:

```
<profile>
    <properties>
      <add name="Username"/>
      <add name="Screenname" />
      <add name="Bio" />
      <add name="ProfilePictureURL" />
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

My C# that assigns the values:

```
 protected void ChangeProfileSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (AssignScreenName.Text != "" || AssignScreenName.Text != null)
        {
            Profile.Screenname = AssignScreenName.Text;
        }
        if (AssignBio.Text != "" || AssignBio.Text != null)
        {
            Profile.Bio = AssignBio.Text;
        }
    }
    Profile.Save();
    Response.Redirect("MyProfile.aspx");
    }
}
```

I'll try to check back here daily to answer comments, so if you need anything feel free to ask! All ideas are welcome, and thanks!

Comment: _"I'll try to check back here daily to answer comments"_ You're not a member for a long time of Stackoverflow, are you? Normally you get response in minutes not days.

Comment: Well you were definitely right... xD

Comment: You're checking not empty OR not null, you probably want not empty AND not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the System.Web section of your Web.Config file to set automaticSaveEnabled = false;

ex.

```
<profile enabled="true" automaticSaveEnabled="false">
```

Cleaner code:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AssignScreenName.Text) Profile.Screenname = AssignScreenName.Text;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AssignBio.Text) Profile.Bio = AssignBio.Text;        
}
Profile.Save();
Response.Redirect("MyProfile.aspx");
```

Also you can use:

```
Profile.SetPropertyValue("propertyname",newvalue);
Profile.Save();
```

example:

```
Profile.SetPropertyValue("Screenname",assignscreenname.Text);
Profile.Save();
```

for each property you'd like to set.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actions are not affected. It seems like our methods act the same way, may I ask the difference?

Comment: @TheNationalSarcasmSociety See my updated answer. The strongly typed accessors do call the setPropertyValue method

Comment: Oh great! Thank you (I like your IF loop one liners, but I was planning to condense the code after I got it working).